# working with map areas on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to check if user is close to some custom area. What would be the best approach to create custom areas (I assume using lat and long points) and checking if user is in/near the area on Android?

Thanks

@edit: would Geofencing be a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate distance between 2 latitude and longitude points with the below example
and you can achieve your objective by using decision statement.

```
  private String getDistance() {
    String dist = new String();
    Location l1 = new Location("One");
    l1.setLatitude(28.684576);
    l1.setLongitude(77.4859711);

    Location l2 = new Location("Two");
    l2.setLatitude(29.684576);
    l2.setLongitude(78.4859711);

    float distance = l1.distanceTo(l2);
    dist = String.format("%.2f", distance) + " m away";
    distanceMeasure.setText(dist);

    if (distance > 1000.0f && distance <3000.0f) {
//decision statement to check whether second position is near your location
  or not

    }
    return dist;
}
```

Comment: ok but how would I then create areas on map, wouldn't it all be much easier with Geofencing, to create the areas and checking if user is in the location?